# PHP Connection to MS SQLServer 2008 from Linux via PDO

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, pdo

I need to connect to a MS SQLServer 2008 service from PHP on Ubuntu, and I would like to do so using PDO. I believe I have installed all the prerequisite libraries, and I am indeed able to connect using `tsql` on the command line and using `mssql_connect()` in code. I can't figure out what the proper DSN is, or if there are any additional PDO-specific configuration steps I am missing.

I am using the following DSN (where `$db*` variables are populated with their appropriate values):

```
odbc:Driver=FreeTDS;SERVER=$dbServer;DATABASE=$dbSchema;UID=$dbUser;PWD=$dbPasswd"
```

My error message is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified' in /home/timothy/test.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 /home/timothy/test.php(4): PDO->__construct('odbc:Driver=Fre...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/timothy/test.php on line 4
```

What additional configuration steps have I over looked?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your php.ini what is this set to? 'mssql.secure_connection' if off turn on and retest. make sure to restart Apache as well

Comment: mssql.secure_connection is off. But keep in mind mssql_* functions work, I'm just trying to use the PDO interface instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need any additional configuration if you can connect with tsql and the mssql extension. You probably just don't have the correct dsn. [This documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.connection.php) should help. Try `new PDO("dblib:host=xx.xx.xx.xx;dbname=mydatabase", "username", "password");`